# Prolong the sound of a word in writing

Tags: poetry, phonetics, sounds, music

How do I prolong the sound of a word in writing, while maintaining its natural sound?
I want to prolong the sound of these words:

> Doh
>   Rei
>   Mi
>   Fah
>   Sol

If I write *Doooooh,* people might read it as *doooo-oh.*

Comment: It's *Do Re Mi Fa Sol La Ti Do.* If you write *Doh*, everybody will think Homer Simpson.

Comment: Homer's phrase is usually written _D'oh!_

Comment: If the context makes it clear that the words come from the musical scale, they'll realize that `Dooooooo` is just an elongated `Do`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like they do in written choral music, use hyphens between the stretched out sounds (similar to what @seagull answered) except it would not be using phonetic spellings, as in their example.

So for Do Re Mi Fa... it might be written as:

> "D-o-o-o, R-e-e-e, M-I-I-I, F-a-a-a, etc.

If it was words instead of sounds, the reader probably wouldn't be confused.

Another method, again borrowed from music, is to draw a line extending out from the word to be stretched, like in this example:

[image: copyrights to Warner Chappell Music Limited]

Answer (score 1):

I recall an old tactic hymn writers used to use where a dash would represent a longer vowel sound.
For instance:

Do-h
Re-i
Mi-
Fa-h
So-l

etc.